# SwiftUI анимация

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Если поместить `DatePicker` в `Form`, то при развертывании/сворачивании ячейки он имеет "кривую" анимацию как на приложенном gif. Как это можно поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Toggle(
                        isOn: $isOnHard,
                        label: {
                            Text("Label")
                    })
                    
                    DatePicker("Time", selection: $enterTime)
                    
                    DatePicker("Time", selection: $fireTime)
                    
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text("Row")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Title")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Если Вам не важна анимация как таковая, для каждого `DatePicker` напишите такую конструкцию:

```
VStack {
    DatePicker("Time", selection: $enterTime)
        .animation(nil)
}
.animation(nil)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Более актуально для iOS 13, так как в iOS 14 `DatePicker` был изменен и более не является "барабаном" (по умолчанию). Ну и для некоторых других элементов, например, `DisclosureGroup`.